# How can i easily extract the percentage of colors of an image?

Tags: perl, colors, imagemagick, extract

I need to extract color information of images in order to be able to search for images based on a percentage of a color later on. I would like to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) for this.
Any ideas?

Comment: Image info? https://metacpan.org/module/Image::Info

Comment: @squiguy: this module does not extract color values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ImageMagick has a `Histogram` method that returns a list of colors in an image and how often they appear. It's poorly documented and has a lousy interface, but I've used it in the past, so I have some helpful code to provide:

```
my @hist_data = $image->Histogram;
my @hist_entries;
# Histogram returns data as a single list, but the list is actually groups of
# 5 elements. Turn it into a list of useful hashes.
while (@hist_data) {
    my ($r, $g, $b, $a, $count) = splice @hist_data, 0, 5;
    push @hist_entries, {
        r => $r,
        g => $g,
        b => $b,
        alpha => $a,
        count => $count,
    };
}
# Sort the colors in decreasing order
@hist_entries = sort { $b->{count} <=> $a->{count} } @hist_entries;
```

However, depending on what you're trying to do, Histogram isn't as useful as it could be for full-color images, because there will be very many slightly different shades of the same color, with the counts split among them in the histogram. A useful pre-processing step is to call `$image->Segment(colorspace => 'rgb')` on a clone of the image, which finds areas of similar colors and replaces the entire area with its average color. Then when you call `Histogram` you will see larger counts for fewer colors, and somewhat more representative data.